Loop Splitting Decreases Performance in Intel Fortran
Compiler: Intel Fortran 2024
Operating System: Windows 11
I'm pretty new to Fortran, working on a Fortran project and found out that the loop splitting will decrease the efficiency dramatically.
For example, the non-splitting version:
      DO k=1,maxz-1
         DO j=1,maxy-1       
            DO i=1,maxx       
             e(i,j,k,1)=e(i,j,k,1)*eeex(i,j,k)
     &           +eexy(i,j,k)*(h(i,j+1,k,3)-h(i,j,k,3))           
     &           -eexz(i,j,k)*(h(i,j,k+1,2)-h(i,j,k,2))
            ENDDO
         ENDDO
      ENDDO

take 1s to run, and the splitting version:
 DO k=1,maxz-1
          DO j=1,maxy-1       
             DO i=1,maxx/2       
              e(i,j,k,1)=e(i,j,k,1)*eeex(i,j,k)
      &           +eexy(i,j,k)*(h(i,j+1,k,3)-h(i,j,k,3))           !eq.2-2-3
      &           -eexz(i,j,k)*(h(i,j,k+1,2)-h(i,j,k,2))           !eeex:eq.2-2-4
             ENDDO
          ENDDO
       ENDDO
       
             DO k=1,maxz-1
          DO j=1,maxy-1        
             DO i=maxx/2+1,maxx       
              e(i,j,k,1)=e(i,j,k,1)*eeex(i,j,k)
      &           +eexy(i,j,k)*(h(i,j+1,k,3)-h(i,j,k,3))           !eq.2-2-3
      &           -eexz(i,j,k)*(h(i,j,k+1,2)-h(i,j,k,2))           !eeex:eq.2-2-4
             ENDDO
          ENDDO
       ENDDO

takes 1.2s to run.
What I've Tried:
I've heard of changing the optimization level between /O2 and /O3 may solve this problem, but I found out that using /O2 merely make it less slower, say, the 1.2s, and the /O3 will take even 1.3s.
So I'm confused right now, about why this happened, and how I could handle this properly.
*ADDED:the more comprehensive code is here FDTD_code

Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Do not use the ` for the apostrophe in English, that is '. Also, on Stack Overflow, in markdown, ` is used to mark code.

if maxx is small (non-constant) value or a non power-of two value, this seems normal to me. What is its value? Ideally, can you share a more reproducible example?

@VladimirFГероямслава Sorry sir I'm new to stackoverflow. I'll do better next time.

@JérômeRichard The maxx is based on the input file, always a constant value, which in my case, is 20.  The more comprehensive code is here FDTD_code. Hope this will help.

Then loop splitting can typically impacts vectorization : SIMD units on mainstream CPUs have generally at least 8 (32-bit) float and 4 (64-bit) double for AVX-2. For AVX-512, it is 16 and 8. It is not clear whether you use simple or double precision in your code, but 10 items is too small for a single precision AVX-512 register and 2x register for double precision. It is not a good idea to split such a small dimension, especially inner-most ones. Not to mention possible bad cache effects (resulting in reloads).

A couple of things that might help you: Build to assembly to see how the compiler optimizes the code (may be something obvious then); turn on optimization diagnostics which may give more info on why the compiler did (or didn't) make a particular optimization choice.

Unfortunately, you did not provide descriptions of arrays, and for loop boundaries you gave only maxx=20. However, due to the wide variety of computing environments, without specific profiling, it is still possible to give only general considerations.
It is clear that the second option (two nested loops) should run slower than the first (one nested loop).
There are three main probable reasons for the magnitude of the slowdown:

If we assume that the dimensions of the arrays coincide with the boundaries of the cycles, then the first option processes the arrays eeex, eexy, eexz and h in a sequence, number by number. And the second option refers to memory with holes, 10 were processed, 10 were skipped, but twice. The analysis of accessing the memory of the array e is more complicated, but it seems to me that due to 3 indexes, the first option is also more optimal;
The overhead costs for organizing an internal cycle are at least 2 times more, for organizing two cycles of 10;
For shorter internal cycles, the possibilities of optimization and vectorization are noticeably less.

To accurately determine the most significant causes, you should analyze execution using Linux perf or Intel VTtune or something similar for instruction statistics and access to cache and RAM.
P.S.
Regarding the impact of clause 1. Often the cache line size is 64 bytes or 8 real(8) numbers, so the second option (two cycles) receives 60% more data into L1 cache. If we consider that the data flow per write (divide by 7 and multiply by 8), then the total loss of memory access to the second option is ≈ 30%.

I do have given the more comprehensive code in the comments of the question, which is here FDTD_code. Sorry for not adding it to the body of the question.
